# javascript Reservation system, checkin checkout date with already booked date

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am looking for help in coding. I ve a booking system similar to airbnb. My issue is related to booking date. To be more specific i ll give you one example

One appartment  is already booked for those following dates 2 dec 2012 till 5 dec 2012:

if a new customer select the following dates from 4 dec 2012 till the 6 dec 2012, it displayed message saying "those dates are already booked".

But if the customer select dates like those one 1 dec til the 6 dec or 29 nov and 10 dec. The system let the customer proceed like if the dates are availables.

To sum up: i d like to make sure that customer will have the message " those dates are already booked" if the period he selected includes dates that have already been booked.

I am not an expert in coding, not at all. But i am quite sure that the problem comes from the javascript that display available Flats.

I will put the entire Js.

The message " those dates are already booked" corresponds to #book_it_disabled_message.

Thank you in advance for you time and skills.

```
function check_inputs(b, c, a) {
b = typeof (b) != "undefined" ? b : true;
c = typeof (c) != "undefined" ? c : "checkin";
a = typeof (a) != "undefined" ? a : "checkout";
if (calendar_is_not_set_date(c)) {
    if (b) {
        calendar_show_cal(c)
    }
    return false
}
if (calendar_is_not_set_date(a)) {
    if (b) {
        calendar_show_cal(a)
    }
    return false
}
return true
}

function copy_checkin_checkout_fields() {
var a = check_inputs(false);
if (a) {
    jQuery("#message_checkin").val(jQuery("#checkin").val());
    jQuery("#message_checkout").val(jQuery("#checkout").val());
    jQuery("#message_number_of_guests").val(jQuery("#number_of_guests").val());
    check_availability_of_dates()
}
}

function copy_message_fields_to_book_it() {
jQuery("#checkin").val(jQuery("#message_checkin").val());
jQuery("#checkout").val(jQuery("#message_checkout").val());
jQuery("#number_of_guests").val(jQuery("#message_number_of_guests").val())
}

function refresh_subtotal() {
var a = function (c, e, d) {
        var b;
        if (c.available) {
            jQuery("#book_it_disabled").hide();
            jQuery("#book_it_enabled").show();
            b = jQuery("#price_amount").html(c.price_per_night).data("nightly-price", c.price_per_night);
            jQuery("#service_fee").html(c.service_fee);
            CogzidelRooms.staggered = c.staggered;
            if (CogzidelRooms.staggered === true) {
                if (CogzidelRooms.stayOffered !== 0) {
                    jQuery("#payment_period").hide();
                    jQuery("#per_month").show();
                    CogzidelRooms.$cancellationVal.text(Translations.long_term);
                    jQuery("#includesFees").show();
                    jQuery("#book_it_default").addClass("monthly")
                }
                jQuery("#subtotal_area").hide();
                jQuery("#show_more_subtotal_info").hide();
                jQuery("#price_amount").text(Cogzidel.Utils.decode(c.staggered_price));
                b.data("monthly-price", c.staggered_price);
                CogzidelRooms.hideMonthlyPriceDetails()
            } else {
                if (CogzidelRooms.stayOffered === 2) {
                    jQuery("#per_month").hide();
                    CogzidelRooms.$cancellationVal.text(CogzidelRooms.originalCancellationPolicy);
                    jQuery("#includesFees").hide();
                    jQuery("#book_it_default").removeClass("monthly");
                    jQuery("#payment_period").show()
                }
                jQuery("#subtotal_area ").show();
                jQuery("#subtotal_area").find("p").show();
                jQuery("#show_more_subtotal_info").show();
                jQuery("#subtotal").html(c.total_price);
                jQuery("#payment_period").val("per_night");
                b.removeAttr("data-monthly-price");
                CogzidelRooms.showMonthlyPriceDetails()
            }
            if (c.can_instant_book) {
                Page3.showInstantBookButton()
            } else {
                Page3.showBookItButton()
            }
        } else {
            if (CogzidelRooms.stayOffered === 1) {
                jQuery("#payment_period").hide();
                jQuery("#per_month").show();
                CogzidelRooms.$cancellationVal.text(Translations.long_term);
                jQuery("#includesFees").show();
                CogzidelRooms.hideMonthlyPriceDetails()
            } else {
                jQuery("#book_it_default").removeClass("monthly");
                jQuery("#payment_period").show();
                jQuery("#per_month").hide();
                  CogzidelRooms.$cancellationVal.text(CogzidelRooms.originalCancellationPolicy);
                jQuery("#includesFees").hide();
                jQuery("#price_amount").html(jQuery("#price_amount").data("nightly-price"));
                CogzidelRooms.showMonthlyPriceDetails()
            }
            jQuery("#book_it_disabled_message").html(c.reason_message);
            jQuery("#book_it_enabled").hide();
            jQuery("#book_it_disabled").show();
            jQuery("#show_more_subtotal_info").hide()
        }
        jQuery("#book_it_status").pulsate(1, 600)
    };
jQuery("#book_it_button").removeAttr("disabled");
jQuery("#subtotal_area").find("p").hide();
jQuery("#subtotal_area").show();
if (calendar_is_not_set_date("checkin") || calendar_is_not_set_date("checkout")) {
    a = function () {};
    jQuery("#book_it_disabled").hide();
    jQuery("#book_it_enabled").show();
    jQuery("#subtotal_area").hide();
    jQuery("#show_more_subtotal_info").hide()
} else {
    jQuery("#subtotal, #book_it_disabled_message").html('<img src="'+base_url+'images/spinner.gif" alt="" height="16" width="16" />')
}
jQuery.getJSON(base_url+"rooms/ajax_refresh_subtotal", jQuery("#book_it_form").serialize(), a)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

From this line:

```
if (calendar_is_not_set_date("checkin") || calendar_is_not_set_date("checkout")) {
```

it appears you are testing date 1 and date 2 in mutually exclusive functions.  You would also have to test every day in between (checkin) and (checkout) if you are just testing 1 day at a time.

Perhaps you need a function that accepts checkin and checkout dates as 2 parameters, and tests to see if that block of dates is available.

Comment: Thanks James, I was thinking of that but i d really have no idea how to implement that. The thing is that if the selected dates are inside dates already booked or if one date (checkin or chekout) is, it will show the message "unavailable date" which is fine. But if the selected dates includes the booking dates it shows dates as available. It s just weird that the period selected is tested if one of the date (checkin or ckeout) is included in a booked period but if its the period already booked that is included between Checkin and checkout selected dates the system will authorize booking.

Comment: I understand your problem, and can see why it happens.  You will have to check the whole range of dates I'm afraid.